# Using Unity, What could cause code to not execute in FixedUpdate(), that does execute when in Update()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on making a counter that increments at a set rate per second. Using the first code snippet it works as intented, but when I changed the Update function to be a FixedUpdate function, as in the second code snippet, the nanoidsValue.text doesn't get updated, and no errors are thrown.

```
public class Nanoids : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    public TMP_Text nanoidsValue;

    public double currentNanoids;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        currentNanoids += 1;
        nanoidsValue.text = currentNanoids.ToString();
    }
}



public class Nanoids : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    public TMP_Text nanoidsValue;

    public double currentNanoids;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        currentNanoids += 1;
        nanoidsValue.text = currentNanoids.ToString();
    }
}
```

According to what I have read Update and FixedUpdate are supposed to only differ in rate that they are executed. Why would the change not be saved to nanoidsValue.text when using FixedUpdate?

P.S. I tried going back and forth multiple times between Update and FixedUpdate, without changing anything else, and this is always the result.

Comment: is your [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) maybe set to `0`? In that case `FixedUpdate` is not called at all ...

Comment: Time.timescsle is set to 0.1f and I also tried it with the default 0.02f.

Comment: From your given code this can then not be reproduced ... it works for me ^^ still questionable why you want to count the calls of `FixedUpdates` ;)